# How do I display the Image of an Author in a post?

Tags: users

This might be a stupid question... but I can't seem to figure it out.

I'd like to show the photo of an author beside their entry. I thought the proper variable was...

```
{{user.photoUrl}}
```

...until I logged out and my photo disappeared.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That will get you the url of the current user's photo. To get an author's photo do this:

```
{{ author.photoUrl }}
```

If the author is not defined in your context but the entry is, then get the entry's author's photo as follows:

```
{{ entry.author.photoUrl }}
```

In Craft 4, the following should be used:

```
{{ entry.author.photo.url ?? '' }}
```

Comment: This method is now deprecated. Does anyone know the current method? The documentation says "Use getPhoto().getUrl() instead." but when I try entry.author.getPhoto().getUrl() I get an error.

Comment: If either the author or photo is not set, it will result in an error. I've updated my answer with a Craft 4 version that falls back to an empty string.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Croker. Hope life is good!